# Where is the "unborable" quote in The Pale King?

Tags: quote-source, david-foster-wallace, the-pale-king

I'm a big fan of The Pale King by David Foster Wallace. I remember a favorite quote somewhere in the text that goes something like the key to life is being unborable...and he met two such men in the summer of... or something.

The quote actually shows up partially [here](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/6498897-the-pale-king) but I can't find the page again. What page is it, so I can get the full quote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found It! Page 440, at the end of Chapter 44. The whole quote is:

> The key is the ability, whether innate or conditioned, to find the other side of the rote, the picayune, the meaningless, the repetitive, the pointlessly complex. To be, in a word, unborable. I met, in the years 1984 and '85, two such men.

> It is the key to modern life. If you are immune to boredom, there is literally nothing you cannot accomplish.